# Get the node ID value after submitting an attached Webform to that node

Tags: 8, nodes, webforms

I have a Webform attached as a field to a specific content type.

After the node is loaded and the Webform is submitted, I am using the below custom webform handler to get the `$webform_submission` values.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_custom_module\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\webformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission;


/**
 * Do something when a webform submission is submitted.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "Do something",
 *   label = @Translation("Do something"),
 *   category = @Translation("any category"),
 *   description = @Translation("Do something"),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class customWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  // Function to be fired while submitting the Webform.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    // Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

    // Get (Full Name) from (full_name) text element available on the webform.
    $fullnamevalue = $values["full_name"];
```

However, I would like to get the "nid" of that node from where the Webform is submitted, so I can load this node by nid to use it in my custom code.

How to get the "nid" of that node from where the Webform is submitted ?

Comment: This information is already available via Tokens in your Email/Handlers.

[current-page:url:args] The specific argument of the current page (e.g. 'arg:1' on the page 'node/1' returns '1').

Comment: I am aware of the tokens but I need to do the explained above via a custom code... Can you clarify more on how to use the tokens from inside the custom code ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer here: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3046808

```
if ($source_entity = $webform_submission->getSourceEntity()) {
   $nid = $source_entity->id();
}
else {
  $nid = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found only the **real Node-ID** with the **referenced webform submission** with this code:

```
$source_entity = $request_handler->getCurrentSourceEntity('webform');
$arrayData = $source_entity->toArray();
$nodeId = intval($arrayData['entity_id'][0]['value']);
```

***$nodeId** will be the node where the webform was in.*